# How do I scroll down to name that I typed using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, highlight

I have a function that highlights,text that I typed:

Search:

```
<input type="text" id="search_term">
<input id="search_button" type="button" value="Find">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#search_button').click(function() {
    var search_term = $('#search_term').val();
    $('*').removeHighlight().highlight(search_term);
});
});
```

But if I have too much stuff on my page,it highlights it, but it doesn't scroll down to it.
What function must I add, so it would scroll down to stuff I have written?

Comment: It was my misstype in code,i didnt copy from my code.
Highlighting works perfectly.

Comment: Why wouldn't you copy/paste from your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
$('yourelementhighlight').animate({scrollTop: $('yourelementhighlight').offset().top}, 2000,'fast');
```

You can have a jquery plugin to scroll to an element : [Scroll to](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)